# react-router access history prop in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

how to access `history` prop from `mapDispatchToProps`

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-native";

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
   doSomething: () => ownProps.history.goBack() // history is undefined ...?? 
})

export default withRouter(connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent))
```

more clearly how to access `react-router` *context props* from within `connect` `mapDispatchToProps` method, the [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) says :

> If your mapDispatchToProps function is declared as taking two parameters, it will be called with dispatch as the first parameter and the props passed to the connected component as the second parameter,

**Update:**

Here is what `react-router`'s [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) says about this

> In most cases, you can use Link, NavLink and Redirect to perform navigation actions. Sometimes you might also need to navigate programmatically, after some asynchronous task that was originally initiated by an action. For example, you might dispatch an action when the user submits a login form. Your thunk, saga or other async handler then authenticates the credentials, then it needs to somehow navigate to a new page if successful. The solution here is simply to include the history object (provided to all route components) in the payload of the action, and your async handler can use this to navigate when appropriate.

obviously there isn't a support for outside context inside a connected component, and need to find a proper clean work around.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way for achieving this is below but first check if history is there in props using console.log.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
 doSomething: (history) => history.goBack() // history is undefined ...?? 
})
```

something like this you can do...

Comment: actually that's my workaround right now, but i don't think that `MyComponent` should care about any side effect implementation, thought take `history` as prop and pass it back to it's parent, all that work is the domain of perent `connected` component.

Answer (score 1):

For any one who will encounter this problem, you **can** access `react-router` context props from `ownProps` in `mapDispatchToProps`, but make sure your ***connected component*** is in one of the following :

1. Passed as component prop to `Router` as `<Route component = { MyConnectedComponent }/>`
2. If it isn't a direct route but nested deep and needs `react-router` props, wrap it with `withRouter()`